# How to make a required `lightning-input-field` field not required?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-inputfield

Is it possible to make a `<lightning-input-field>` where `field-name` is required (such as `Contact.LastName`) **not required** on the UI?

I would like the field to not kick in validation rules (client ones) and not to have the `required` styling once I submit, but it still happens when setting `required` to `false`.

Sample code:

```
    <lightning-record-edit-form
      object-api-name="Contact"
      form-class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-m-left--xx-large slds-m-bottom--medium"
      onsubmit={handleSearch}
    >
      <template for:each={searchFields} for:item="field">
        <div key={field.name} class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-4">
          <lightning-input-field field-name={field.name} value={field.value} required={isFalse}></lightning-input-field>
        </div>
      </template>
      <div class="slds-col_bump-left slds-p-top--large">
        <lightning-button class="slds-p-right--large" label="Search" type="submit"></lightning-button>
      </div>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

In the JavaScript file:

```
  get isFalse() {
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using a lightning-record-edit-form, it automatically enforces any validations that salesforce has, in this case the contact.LastName being required.

If you want to make the field 'not required' from the UI, you should not be using the edit-form, hence even the lightning-input-field, the alternative to do this would be, to use the 'lightning-input' element and mark the required=false, but we need to keep in mind that, if it is required from salesforce, it would throw an error. Since you cannot override the salesforce validations from UI. Hope it helps.